# What is the optimal way to mow a lawn?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

To set the stage, I'm trying to inform my neighbors of the most efficient way to mow their multi-acre lawn because it takes quite long with their current arrangement.

Say you have the outline of an irregular shape (the boundary of a person's lawn) with another shape inset (their house). The area of the second subtracted from the first describes the lawn which you're attempting to fully cover in the most efficient manner by the path your lawnmover takes. Imagine the path of a theoretical lawnmover is of a specific width, and can be traced continuously from start to finish, like a rope. If you have a 'rope' with maximum bend radius equal to the rope's diameter, or the width that the lawnmover cuts (turning the lawnmover on a dime), what are some techniques you could apply to solve for the optimal path that that rope should be laid in to fully cover the lawn?

Is there any graph theory to describe how to solve the problem I'm posing that anyone on this board could point me towards? I am familiar with Euler's Königsberg bridges, but am not sure how to abstract out this problem to that. I have python processing the image and an outline of the shape that needs to be filled in, with a misshapen void in the middle representing the house. As a disclaimer, I am absolutely not a math major, and currently still in undergrad.

Alternatively, since I don't know the exact 'width' of said lawnmover, is it true that always cutting in a spiral, starting at the outside of the lawn and curling in towards the house, is the most efficient option? Thank you so much for helping me try to understand.

Comment: Define “efficient”.

Comment: Hi, sorry. Realized I omitted this. I'd define efficient possibly in terms of needing to make the least amount of turns, since that's the motion that cuts the least grass while running the motor at an equal rpm as when cutting.

Comment: Are you asking how to mow the entire area in one continuous sweep without walking back to mow some little patches of grass you missed? If so, then wouldn't it be better to have your neighbors mow their lawn by starting at one end of the lawn and traveling either up or down to mow one strip, turn, mow the next strip in the opposite direction, and repeat? And this is not using any math. It's something any lawnmower would think of, I would guess.

Comment: @Accelerator I think it's a bit more fun than that. If you think about efficiency as grass blades cut per rotation of the lawnmover's blade, every increase in curvature of the path of the lawnmover makes it slightly less efficient, since the inside of the lawnmower is slightly less productive than the outside of the turn. So it’s an optimization problem of covering the inside of the shape with the least accumulated curvature. 
the cool thing about this is you weight turns as greater killers to efficiency if you have a wider lawnmover

Comment: A counterpoint to your point is having a circular lawn. It's absolutely not the most efficient to mow it in straight pieces and make 180 deg turns, it's probably to use a gradual helical pattern. I'm seeking a way to abstract away knowledge of what shape you might have and apply a general rule to get the most efficient path. But you are innately understanding that mowing with infinite curvature is most efficient, since the blade is cutting the same amount of grass on both sides of the motor.